# cannot convert from char to void*

Tags: c++, windows

```
SAFEARRAYBOUND bound[1] = {25, 0};
SAFEARRAY * psa = SafeArrayCreate(VT_UI1, 1, bound);
for(long int i = 0; i <25; i++)
    SafeArrayPutElement(psa, &i,sendBuf[i]);
```

I am trying to creating a [safearray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ec8025b-4763-4526-ab45-390c5d8b3b1e%28VS.85%29) from a char array but get this error `cannot convert from char to void*`
sendBuf is a char array

Comment: you probably need to tell us the definition of SAFEARRAY/BOUND

Comment: @user What is `sendBuf` ? If it is a character array, then `sendBuf[i]` gives the character at that index.

Comment: You also forgot to include the error you are getting.

Comment: *... but get this error*. Which error?

Comment: SAFEARRAY is defined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ec8025b-4763-4526-ab45-390c5d8b3b1e(VS.85) and SAFEARRAYBOUND is in that section as well.

Comment: SO mangled the URL. Add a right paren after clicking

Comment: @mkb - didn't realise it was a microsoft 'standard' call because it's not called hLONG_POINTER_TO_SAFE_ARRAY_BOUNDS and doesn't take a large opaque struct as the first argument ;-)

Comment: @MartinBeckett Even the SAFEARRAY itself isn't opaque. I'm impressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't show us the error, but it appears `SafeArrayPutElement` takes a *pointer* to the element as the third parameter.  I believe it'll work if you use:

```
SafeArrayPutElement(psa, &i, &sendBuf[i]);
```

Note the `&`.

Comment: I think, technically speaking, OP should create this array with VT_I1, since the source `sendBuf` is a signed type.

Answer (score 1):

It would be more efficient in this case to use `SafeArrayAccessData()` instead of `SafeArrayPutElement()`:

```
SAFEARRAYBOUND bound[1] = {25, 0}; 
SAFEARRAY * psa = SafeArrayCreate(VT_UI1, 1, bound); 
void *pvData;
SafeArrayAccessData(psa, &pvData);
memcpy(pvData, sendBuf, 25);
SafeArrayUnaccessData(psa);
```

Or:

```
SAFEARRAYBOUND bound[1] = {25, 0}; 
SAFEARRAY * psa = SafeArrayCreate(VT_UI1, 1, bound); 
unsigned char *pvData;
SafeArrayAccessData(psa, (void**)&pvData);
for(long int i = 0; i <25; i++)     
    pvData[i] = sendBuf[i];
SafeArrayUnaccessData(psa);
```